# Creating a global Datastore client

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What are the conventions around when and where to create datastore client objects?

```
datastore = new Datastore({});
```

In the docs a new Datastore instance seems to be created in every single file. Would there be any benefit in creating a singleton that initialises the Datastore connection and returns the same instance to each part of the application that requires it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the underlying code if `new Datastore({})` actually creates a new instance or returns a singleton, you'd have to check that.

What you could do is move the creation of the datastore instance to a seperate file and `require` that instance in every file you need access to datastore. Since dependencies you `require` are cached you will always get the same instance.

Pseudo code:
datastore.js

```
const datastore = new Datastore({});

module.exports = datastore;
```

foo.js

```
const datastore = require('./datastore');

// do something with datastore
```

---

In reply to your follow-up question.

If you look at the source code of the nodejs/Datastore module you will see the same pattern:

src/index.js

```
* @example <caption>Import the client library</caption>
* const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
// ...
module.exports = Datastore;
```

No matter where you require the client library:

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
```

It will always return the same instance. Datastore will handle scaling and connections (pooling) for you.

In conclusion: There's no functional difference between requiring the client library in each file or wrapping it in a seperate file and require that in the files where you need a connection.

Personally, I prefer wrapping the connection in a seperate file and require that in my data access files. Benefits for this are:
* You abstract away the actual implementation. If you ever need to change datastore or the way you connect to it it will only ever be in one place.
* In case you need to supply connection parameters (like a password) you only have to do that once. It saves you from writing the same code over and over again.

Comment: But is there any advantage or disadvantage to having the same instance shared like this across my whole application? From a maintainability standpoint I like this approach, but I want to be sure that it isn't going to break anything as my app grows.

Comment: @MattC Edited my original answer with an answer to your question.